# Circular Array-Based Queue Insert Class Method - Python

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

I am trying to implement the insert method of a circular array-based queue, however am unable to update the rear of the queue. Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, max_size):

"""
        -------------------------------------------------------

        Initializes an empty queue. Data is stored in a fixed-size list.
        Use: cq = Queue(max_size)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Parameters:
            max_size - maximum size of the queue (int > 0)
        Returns:
            a new Queue object (Queue)
        -------------------------------------------------------
        """
        assert max_size > 0, "Queue size must be > 0"

        self._max_size = max_size
        self._values = [None] * self._max_size
        self._front = 0
        self._rear = 0
        self._count = 0
def insert(self, value):

        '''-------------------------------------------------------
        Adds a copy of value to the rear of the queue.
        Use: cq.insert( value )
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Parameters:
            value - a data element (?)
        Returns:
            None
        -------------------------------------------------------'''
        assert (self._count < self._max_size), 'queue is full'
        self._values.append(deepcopy(value))
        self._count += 1
        self._rear = (self._rear - 1) % self._count
        return
```

Any suggestions?

edit:
here is the remove implementation:

```
def remove(self):

        '''-------------------------------------------------------
        Removes and returns value from the queue.
        Use: v = cq.remove()
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Returns:
            value - the value at the front of the queue - the value is
                removed from the queue (?)
        -------------------------------------------------------'''
        assert (self._count > 0), 'Cannot remove from an empty queue'
        value = self._values[self._front]
        self._front = (self._front + 1) % self._count
        self._count += -1
        return value
```

Comment: Suggestion: use `collections.deque`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "unable to update the rear of the queue".  Does that mean that you're adding more to the queue than its max_size?  You didn't include any function that removes from the queue; do you have one?  (It may help to read up on providing a [mcve].)  You may also benefit from taking the [tour], and reading up on [ask].

Comment: @ScottMermelstein What I mean is that when a value is added to the queue, self._rear is not updated properly. The value I insert is not added to the rear of the queue

Comment: General advice - try printing the value of `self._rear` after you set it, so you can see if it's behaving the way you expect.  Then you can look and see if `self._values[self._rear]` (**not** `self._rear`) is the value you expect it to be.  Offhand, I would question strongly if your `% self._count` does what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

When you add items by appending, you are extending your list beyond the max length that you pre-allocated it to. You then update `self._rear` as if you were going to use it as the insert index, but never actually use it for anything. I have implemented your code with only very minor changes beyond variable names (in order to make more sense to me), and utilizing `self._rear (now: self._write_cursor)` in the way I believe you intended.

```
class CQ: #Circular Queue
    def __init__(self, maxsize): 
        self._maxsize = maxsize
        self._write_cursor = 0
        self._read_cursor = 0
        self._len = 0
        self._values = [None] * maxsize

    def insert(self, item):
        if self._len < self._maxsize:
            self._values[self._write_cursor] = item
            self._write_cursor = (self._write_cursor + 1) % self._maxsize
            self._len = self._len + 1
        else:
            raise IndexError('can\'t push to full queue')

    def remove(self):
        if self._len > 0:
            out = self._values[self._read_cursor]
            self._read_cursor = (self._read_cursor + 1) % self._maxsize
            self._len -= 1
            return out
        else:
            raise IndexError('can\'t pop from empty queue')
```

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I see where your're coming from. I tend to associate "push" and "pop" with any `lifo` data structure, and generally don't bother to make the change when it's `fifo` like here.